# How can I run Bitcoin Core with the -zapwallettxes option in Windows OS

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, windows

I have been trying to run Bitcoin Core with -zapwallettxes option by starting the command line prompt, and typing (cmd.exe) Start bitcoin-qt with --zapwallettxes=1 but it keeps saying Windows cannot find bitcoin-qt. I am trying to remove a stuck transaction and have the bitcoins back in my wallet. Any help would be much appreciated.

James

Answer (score 1):

First always backup your wallet.dat prior to actions then

Try running

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt" --zapwallettxes=1
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt" --zapwallettxes=1
```